# Building wheel for wxpython (setup.py) ... error Windows

Tags: python, pip, wxpython

I've been trying to install wxpython on Windows and I simply cannot find out why I repeated get this error when trying to build the wheel for wxpython.  This is for a collaborative project and none of my other groupmates have had this issue and we followed similar steps.  The full error message is included below:

[Error Message 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b45PQ.png)
[Error Message 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfCY7.png)

From there, it looks like it tries to continue the installation but can't because the wheel failed to build, and prints a similarly large error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at the bottom of your first image, it tells you the reason:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required
```

And after that it tells you a link to download the c++ build tools.

Some python library like pywin32 needs extra libraries like Microsoft Visual C++ build tool, to install properly.

Comment: As far as I know I should have installed the C++ build tool correctly as instructed, but I still get the same error, with that message about the requirement as well.  Perhaps it doesn't have access to the tools somehow?

Comment: That is strange, all I can suggest at this point is to uninstall the previous installation of the C++ tool and reinstall it. Maybe your old version isn't the correct version?